# Neo4j - cypher - variable length pattern slow

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm playing around with neo4j and cypher and trying to find out why my query is slow.

Here is my original query that is marked as deprecated:

```
match (h:Hierarchy)-[r:PARENT_OF*1..4]->(s:SoldTo)
where  h.id='0100001709' 
    and all(x in r 
        where x.to>=date('2022-02-15') 
        and x.from <= date('2022-02-15') 
        and x.hvkorg='S000'
        and x.hvtweg='D1'
)
and s.loevm=""
and s.aufsd=""    
and s.cassd=""
and s.faksd=""
and s.lifsd=""
and s.sperr=""
and s.sperz=""
r>eturn distinct  h.id,s.id
```

This one works fine and returns a result quite quickly: `Started streaming 60 records after 1 ms and completed after 17 ms.` However neo4j gives the below warning:

> This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
> Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated. (Binding a variable length relationship pattern to a variable ('r') is deprecated and will be unsupported in a future version. The recommended way is to bind the whole path to a variable, then extract the relationships:
> MATCH p = (...)-[...]-(...)
> WITH *, relationships(p) AS r)

Now, i've tried this:

```
match p=(h:Hierarchy)-[:PARENT_OF*1..4]->(s:SoldTo)
with *, relationships(p) as r
where  h.id='0100001709' 
and all(x in r 
    where x.to>=date('2022-02-15') 
        and x.from <= date('2022-02-15') 
        and x.hvkorg='S000'
        and x.hvtweg='D1'
)
and s.loevm=""
and s.aufsd=""    
and s.cassd=""
and s.faksd=""
and s.lifsd=""
and s.sperr=""
and s.sperz=""
return distinct  h.id,s.id
```

But, this is very slow: `Started streaming 60 records in less than 1 ms and completed after 36931 ms.`

**17ms vs 36931ms**

Would any of you have any recommendation to speed things up using relationships()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo error on the query. Instead of doing a scan on the first line, put the where clause (found in line #3 to line#2).  This will enable a starting node at h and will make your query faster.

```
Original:
match p=(h:Hierarchy)-[:PARENT_OF*1..4]->(s:SoldTo)
with *, relationships(p) as r
where  h.id='0100001709' 

Updated:
match p=(h:Hierarchy)-[:PARENT_OF*1..4]->(s:SoldTo)
where  h.id='0100001709' 
with h, s, relationships(p) as r
...
...
return distinct  h.id,s.id
```